# Eclipse does not parse new class file

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created one class file in eclipse IDE. However, Eclipse does not include that file in the searching list when I press Ctrl + T for searching a type. I don't know why this happens. Has anyone met this problem before? What's the solution? Thanks for help.

P/S: I'm using PDT plugin for Eclipse
Eclipse autocomplete function also didn't work, when I press Ctrl + , there's no autocomplete list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem by myself. I inspected the log file of Eclipse and see that there're some problem with the workspace. I deleted the workspace and created new workspace with old project. The problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Make sure the file is in a source folder in a Java project. If you just create an arbitrary .java file somewhere, it doesn't necessarily get compiled (and added to the list of types for the type browser) - it has to be on the build path of a Java project.
- If 'Build Automatically' is not turned on, have you built the project?
- Occasionally, projects can get in a weird state. Try cleaning the project (Project > Clean...).

Comment: I'm using PDT Plugin for eclipse. Sorry for lack of information